# Asp.net MVC 3 JSON Model Binders

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, modelbinders

So I have this JSON

```
mrn:"0760433"
res:[{"registry":1,"episodeType":{"id":6,"dateAndTime":"08-06-2012 13:21"}}]
```

And I have these view models

```
    public class patient
    {
        public string mrn { get; set; }

    }

    public class episodeType
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string dateAndTime { get; set; }
    }

    public class registryEpisode 
    {
        public int registry { get; set; }
        public episodeType episodeType { get; set; }

       public registryEpisode()
       {
           registry = 0;
           episodeType = new episodeType();
       }
    }
```

And this controller signature:

```
public JsonResult StartSession(string mrn, List<registryEpisode> res)
```

When I post, res is ALWAYS null.  Any thoughts?  What am I doing wrong?  Yes, I am posting, yes I am using jquery:

```
$.post('Action', data, function () {});
```

Yes, I do get to my Action on my controller, but res is null.  Help!  Thanks in advance as always...!

Comment: I'm not sure but the date seems a bit strange? If I write JSON.stringify(new Date()) I get another format... For easy debug, try to remove some of your property in the .NET class and see which one mess things up...

Comment: The date property is a string...it should be ok no matter the format.  I removed all the properties...they funny thing is the MRN is coming across with any issues...its the collection that's the problem

Comment: Some more info, when I look at Request.Form["res"] in the command window while debugging I get the following: [{\"registry\":1,\"episodeType\":{\"id\":6,\"dateAndTime\":\"08-06-2012 13:57\"}}].  I still can't seem to see where the issue is.  Is this a limitation of the model binder?  Do I need to implement my own?

Comment: No it should work I don't have time to test it by my own. Try to download an example and serach for diffencies.

Comment: I wasn't sending application/json to the server.  Now I am, and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

So this was an interesting one to resolve...I'm using knockout.  Knockout has a few features in it that allow you to deliver you viewModel as either a pojo (plain old JSON object) or a pojso (plain old javascript object).

So here's the duh moment...the asp.net model binder is expecting a stringified JSON string for conversion.  Knockout's toJSON stringifies viewModels already, so when you have a primative type like a string and a collection as arguments to your action you have to get the value of the primitive type like

`var m = self.model.property();`

then get the collection as a pojso, like

`var c = ko.toJS(self.model.collection)`

then stringify them as one complete view model like

`var data = JSON.stringify({prop1: m, prop2: c});`.

Finally, you send the model server side with a jquery ajax call to a Action method like

`public JsonResult StartSession(string prop1, IList<registryEpisode> prop2){}`

That apparently does the trick.  Seems like a hack to me, but it works.  Hope this helps someone else.